# ironSpotfire Pop-up for loading locally stored data and execute query

Tags: button, file-upload, ironpython, spotfire

Here is what I am trying to achieve in Spotfire but I am not sure if I can really do it with IronPython..
1- Create a button that opens a pop-up window and asks the user for the path to up-load a locally-stored csv file

2- Once the file is loading in the spotfire report, execute a left outer join query between these new data and a data table stored in the spotfire report.

The idea is to give the user the possibility to load their own data and extract the corresponding data from the report.

Regards

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Spotfire doesn't support creating popups like this. and if you cannot trust your users enough to use the Spotfire Analyst client, can you really trust them enough to add well-formed data to the analysis? I think you would have a lot of support issues with this approach..